# Use $(el).addClass('example'); but don't add on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, I know the title might be strange. Basically, I have the code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('body.single article.project').addClass('grayscale');
});
```

The problem is that adding the class of `grayscale` on load initializes the plugin that corresponds to that class, which I *don't* want to do. I would like to add the class but not initialize the plugin.

Would I have to somehow add the class a few milliseconds after load? How would I go about this?

Comment: use a timer... like `setTimeout(function(){$('body.single article.project').addClass('grayscale');}, 100)`

Comment: Why not use a different class name?

Comment: @Jezen Because I want that class to be there to later work with the plugin.

Comment: You could of course explicitly add the classname when you explicitly initialise the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plugin has a self initialization script, then that will be running in dom ready handler. So one solution could be is to use a timer to delay your addClass() by few milliseconds

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('body.single article.project').addClass('grayscale');
    }, 100)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout you can add the desired class after page load (e.g 100 ms):

```
$(window).load(function(){
var t=setTimeout(
function(){$("body.single article.project").addClass("grayscale");}, 100)
})
```